# Alembic autogenerate not detecting current state

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

#### Problem

I'm using Alembic autogenerate to migrate some model changes. I run alembic revision/upgrade once and it properly creates my table and adds an alembic_version table to my database. When I go to run the revision/upgrade command again, it tries to recreate the table despite no changes being made to the model

```
alembic.command.revision(cfg, autogenerate=True)
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'alias.alias'
```

As you can see here it's attempting to add the table alias.alias even though it already exists in my database and was created by Alembic in the first revision/upgrade command.

[image: Database after first revision]

Predictably, when I attempt to run the second upgrade I get the error

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "alias" already exists
```

#### Current setup

env.py

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/')

from logging.config import fileConfig
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from alembic import context
from models.Base import Base
from models import Alias

config = context.config

fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata

def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Alias.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from models.Base import Base


class Alias(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alias'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'alias'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chart_config = Column(String)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    display_name = Column(String)
    datasets = Column(String)
```

Base.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

#### Expected outcome

How do I get alembic to detect that the alias.alias table already exists? It should autogenerate an empty revision. The model Alias.py is completely static during my 2 runs of revision/upgrade

Answer (score -1):

Solved by editing alembic's env.py to include schemas

```
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
        connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata,
        include_schemas = True # Include this
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()
```